# libgdx how to access power button of android device?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I just want to check that the power button is pressed or not in LibGDX and if it is pressed then exit/close the game or something else like change screen.
I used this code:

```
@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {

    sb.begin();

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.POWER)){
        Gdx.app.exit();
    }
    sb.end();

}
```

but this is not working. After I press the button screen turns off and when I turn it back on the game resumes from exactly where I left it.
I wanted to keep the screen on on power button press but I didn't find any solution on that.
Now I at least want to access the button and then do something on button press.

the same code works for volume up/down button.
Code:

```
@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {

    sb.begin();


    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.VOLUME_UP)){
        Gdx.app.exit();
    }
    sb.end();

}
```

Please describe if I'm doing anything wrong and what shall I do.

Comment: I am not sure if you can catch it, for me I would try to catch it in Android application and send interface to game project

Answer (score 1):

You can do all saves in `pause` method that is available in `Screen` and `ApplicationListener` classes. It will be called when you exit the app or block device.

```
@Override
public void pause () {
      // save here
}
```